# Fetch hour from the hour column of pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an Hour column from which I want to fetch only the hour values and put them in another column in the data frame.

The data looks like this,
Hour
09:01:00
09:20:00
09:35:00
09:48:00

What I want is
09:01:00  -    9(new_value)
09:20:00  -    9(new_value)
09:35:00. -    10(new_value)
09:48:00  -    10(new_value)

since the time is 09:35:00, I want to count it as 10 hours because it has crossed the half-hour mark.

dt.hour gives,

new_values
9
9
9
9

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['New'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.round('1H').dt.hour
print (df)
       Hour  New
0  09:01:00    9
1  09:20:00    9
2  09:35:00   10
3  09:48:00   10
```